# WooCommerce default variation "Add to Cart", passing a variable to filter hook and template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a variable to the WooCommerce woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args filter hook without editing the wc-template-functions.php file.

I'd like to have an active "Add to Cart" button defaulting to the correct variation for a variable product on both the Product page and the Shop page.

I have a function that selects a variation and returns an object with keys 'id' and 'index' for that variation.

I have a custom template variable.php file that filters the $available_variations array by the 'id' value.

I'm currently calling this function a second time and using the returned object 'index' value to select the variation in the woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args filter hook which is called with an apply_filters in the wc-template-functions.php file.

Is there a way to call the function that selects a variation and returns its 'id' and 'index' once and pass the returned object to both the woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args filter and to the function in the variable.php template file?

Alternatively, is there a more elegant solution to activate the "Add to Cart" button for the correct default variation on both the Product page and the Shop page?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the id and index with PHP just use JavaScript to set the default variation and to update the "Add to Cart" button.

You can do it on both the Product page and the Shop page, just use JavaScript to read the default variation data and set the selected variation accordingly.